# yii uploading files error

Tags: yii

i'm a Portuguese student and i'm trying to implement a web application for game's management.

structure for table `game`

```
`game` (
`idGame` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`primaryScreen` blob NOT NULL,
`game_content` blob NOT NULL,
`category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`platform` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`device` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`funcionalities` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idGame`)
)

`screen` (
`idScreen` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_Game` int(11) NOT NULL,
`image` longblob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idScreen`),
KEY `id_Game` (`id_Game`)
)
```

i have read a yii tutorial of how to upload a file to a bolb in a database
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/95/saving-files-to-a-blob-field-in-the-database

the only difference is that in the function before save i only want to keep the content of file (can i do this or do i have to keep file name, file extension...)
so i do like this in model:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
if($file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'game_uploaded'))
{
// $this->file_name=$file->name;
//$this->file_type=$file->type;
//$this->file_size=$file->size;
$this->game_content=file_get_contents($file->tempName);
//$file->saveAs('path/to/uploads');

}
if($file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'primscreen'))
{
//$this->file_name=$file->name;
//$this->file_type=$file->type;
//$this->file_size=$file->size;
$this->primaryScreen=file_get_contents($file->tempName);
//$file->saveAs('path/to/uploads');
}




return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

but when i try i have this error:

```
PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away
```

could someone help me please?
i appreciate any suggestion. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At Your config file

Try to change its host from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use base64_encode before saving to database

Bom trabalho!

Answer (score 0):

1. One common cause of `MySQL server has gone away` is because of a timeout. Try to increase the `default_socket_timeout` as so:

   ```
   ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
   ```
2. Another could be the size of the blob. Try increasing your upload size limit in the `php.ini`

   ```
   post_max_size
   upload_max_filesize
   ```